# B2B Recipe install issue in SAP Hybris 6.2

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

[image]I just installed b2c_acc_plus recipe and after it i also installed powertools B2B add on. When i am trying to access the accelerator website, i am getting a message on browser "Server Error". However strangely the Platform site is working. The server logs are also not showing any error.

I changed the host file. In HAC/Extentions all the B2C and B2B extention are showing installed.

Before installing the B2B addons the B2C sites were working, server logs are showing cronjobs for B2C & B2B. Any idea what could be problem?

Comment: Please share the exact error that is shown. Maybe there were errors during startup?

Comment: From my experinece there is an issue with the `SAPB2CCustomerAccountService` in this addon. But without the stackstrace it is definitly hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: Your question lacks important information like version of Hybris, the link/steps that you followed, the list of sites which as accessible/inaccessible, a screenshot of the browser showing the error etc.

Comment: i've added the screenshot. The server logs in the debug mode is also not showing. Hybris V6.2

Answer (score 1):

In case an error is thrown, the tomcat server logs are very helpful.

Not sure how you started the application with a recipe or by executing `hybrisserver.sh` (on linux) in the `.../hybris/bin/platform` folder. You can take a look in the tomcat logfile directly in `.../hybris/log/tomcat/console<date>.log` file.

Without this, it's very hard to providing help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set logging level to debug and make sure you're passing site name in the URL. E.g. `.../yacceleratorstorefront?site=electronics`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get `trainingstorefront`? If you are using OOTB accelerator, it would be `yacceleratorstorefront`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to hit below URL and it should work.

http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/?site=electronics&clear=true
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/?site=apparel-uk&clear=true

for https please change the port to 9002.